# Raspberry pi, C++ chrono function, operations on values?

Tags: c++, frequency, c++-chrono

I am beginning in C++ and with the "chrono" function, and I'd like to use it to get the speed of a motor.

For that, I have a coding wheel linked to a motor, an optocoupler is used to gather the square signal generated by the coding wheel.

Therefore, my raspberry pi receive a square signal which speed depends on the motor speed.

I used the chrono function to try to calculate the duration of the frequency of the square signal.
I achieved to have the duration of each signal (almost) which is 7ms.
I'd like to simply extract the frequency through the formula 1/F (therefore, 1/0.007 = 142.85).

I've been eating the documentation of the chrono function for a week, and I still don't get it at all...

Apparently, all the answers are here, but I don't understand that, I'm still a beginner in C++ :( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

This has been REALLY usefull, but limited : https://www.code57.com/cplusplus-programming-beginners-tutorial-utilities-chrono/

If I understand right, the "value" of 7ms is stored in an "object"... 
How can I simply get it out of there and put it in a standard variable so I can divide, multiply and do whatever I want with it?

Here is the interresting part of the C++ code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <csignal>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

// global flag used to exit from the main loop
bool RUNNING = true;
bool StartTimer = false;
//int timer = 0;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point BeginMeasurement; //chrono variable representing the beginning of the measurement of a motor speed


//some more code in here, but nothing exceptionnal, just calling the interruption when needed


//interruption function for counting the motor speed
void RPMCounter(){
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    if (StartTimer == true){
    StartTimer = false;
    steady_clock::duration result = steady_clock::now()-BeginMeasurement;
    if (duration_cast<milliseconds>(result).count() < 150){
        double freq;
        //cout.precision(4);
        std::cout << "Time = " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(result).count() << " ms" << '\n';
// I would like the next line to work and give me the frequency of the detection...
        freq = 1/(duration_cast<milliseconds>(result).count()/1000);
        std::cout << "Frequency = " << freq << " Hz" << '\n';
    }
    }
    else{
    BeginMeasurement = steady_clock::now();
    StartTimer = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the result in my command prompt :

[image]

the value of 7ms increases because I stopped the motor, therefore, it was turning slower until stopping ;)

**Edit :**

Thanks to Howard Hinnant and Ted Lyngmo, My code now looks like this :

```cpp
void RPMCounter(){
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    if (StartTimer == true){
    StartTimer = false;
    duration<double> result = steady_clock::now() - BeginMeasurement;
    if (result < milliseconds{150}){
        double freq;//= 1s / result;
        //cout.precision(4);
        std::cout << "Time = " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(result).count() << " ms" << '\n';
        freq = (1.0/(duration<double>{result}.count()/1000))/1000;
        std::cout << "Frequency = " << freq << " Hz" << '\n';
    }
    }
    else{
    BeginMeasurement = steady_clock::now();
    StartTimer = true;
    }
}
```

and it seems to give me a correct frequency.
As i'm a beginner, I'll surely understand all that better in a while and improve it :) 
(basically, I'm not exactly sure of what I wrote mean... like the "::" and other ways of  :)
The rest of my coding should be more basic and allow me to learn all the tweaks of C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make the `result` a `double` based duration:

```
auto BeginMeasurement = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); 

// some work

// a double based duration
std::chrono::duration<double> result = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - BeginMeasurement;
```

You can then divide the *`duration`* `1s` with `result` to get the frequency:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

double freq = 1s / result;
std::cout << freq << " Hz\n";
```

[Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) pointed out that from C++14 you can make it even easier for youself by changing the dividend from an integer based duration, `1s`, to a double based duration, `1.0s`, and let `result` be deduced using `auto`:

```
auto result = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - BeginMeasurement;
double freq = 1.0s / result;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/kma277)

Comment: Perhaps another tweak:  `double freq = 1.0s / result;`.  Now you don't even have to make `result` a double-based duration.  One can just declare `auto result = ...;`.  Disclaimer:  This answer requires C++14 or better.  In C++11 it isn't quite as pretty but one could do `double freq = duration<double>{1} / result;`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thank you Howard! That tweak makes it much nicer indeed!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks a lot for your answer, I'm not really sure to clearly understand everything but I'm learning, I guess that after a few hundred lines of code i'll understand better. As said on the last answer, no idea on what version of C++ I am, and no idea how to check that...

Comment: @zepeu Thanks! I'm pretty sure I don't understand everything going on in `<chrono>` either, but now when I look at Howards tweak, it seems obvious. `int / int => int` and `int / double => double` and `double / int => double` when doing normal calculations, so why shouldn't it be true here too? I learnt something.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Tell me, how can I simply get the numbers out of these objects? I mean, I want to write "freq = 1/result" and not "1s/result" that's really annoying, I know if it's seconds, micro or nanoseconds, I want to do simple basic arythmectics, and I just had a compilator error because I didn't precise it was seconds...

Comment: @zepeu You have the `count()` member function in the `duration` that returns the value of the underlying type - but I would advice you to stay within the `duration` domain for as long as possible. Extracting the numbers to do calculations, possibly mixing different units, is error prone and often less efficient. The `duration`s carries the unit information so you don't have to possibly get that wrong. It also makes it a lot easy to read and maintain. `7.8s / 5ms` beats `7.8 * 1000 / 5` in my book.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I always work with international units, so problems vanish "7.8s / 5ms or 7.8*1000/5" => 7.8/0.005 s. The thing is that I have no idea how all these "chrono" things work, I am a real beginner in C++ (not in programming) ^^, when you say "the duration domain", I should write things like "std::chrono::duration<double> 1Turn = (std::chrono::duration<double> Duration1tick * std::chrono::duration<double> Nbticks);" then "std::chrono::duration<double> freq = 1/1Turn;"?  I want just "OneTurn  = Duration1tick * Nbticks;" and  "freq  = 1/ 1Turn;" (count time a motor take to do 1 turn)...

Comment: "_7.8/0.005_" - yes, what I mean is that you can mix unit sizes (milli, micro, nano etc) and even those with different ratios (1/1000, 1/60, 1/24 ...) and do calculations with those mixed with very little effort. I don't mean you should convert things that are not already durations into that domain, that won't work, but a when you have two durations (1s and the duration between events), it makes sense to make the calculation using durations, like in `1.0s / 7ms` for example.

Comment: @zepeu This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It will cost you an hour.

Comment: @HowardHinnant You're my savior, I'll check that this evening :) Thanks a lot to you too

Answer (score 4):

> `if (duration_cast<milliseconds>(result).count() < 150){`

You can simplify this with:

```
if (result < 150ms)
```

Or if you're in C++11:

```
if (result < milliseconds{150})
```

The advantage is that you don't have to truncate result to a courser precision, and the code is just easier to read.

> `freq = 1/(duration_cast<milliseconds>(result).count()/1000);`

Instead:

```
using dsec = duration<double>;  // define a double-based second
auto freq = 1/dsec{result}.count();
```

This could also be written:

```
auto freq = 1/duration<double>{result}.count();
```

In any event, this converts `result` straight to double-based seconds, and inverts that value using floating point arithmetic.  The original code uses integral division resulting in an integral result that is always rounding down to 0.  I.e. `1/10 == 0`, whereas `1/10. == 0.1`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I start to understand a bit better how this works, and I have my first results... Still a lot to go before I really understand all that :) On the other hand, no idea on what version of C++ I am, and no idea how to check that...

Comment: What compiler are you using and what does this output: `std::cout << __cplusplus;`?

Comment: I use Geany, and the line "std::cout << __cplusplus;" don't give any output. I've added it to the main of my program. 2 underscores before cplusplus? I apparently have gcc 8.3.0 if it means anything

Comment: Yes, 2 underscores there.  gcc 8.3.0 is a modern compiler supporting all current versions of C++: C++11/14/17.  You can set the version with the command-line argument `-std=c++17` (for C++17 for example).  `__cplusplus`  is a macro defined to an integral type with a value such as 201703, indicating that the version is C++17.  This represents the year and month of the specification it is implementing.

Comment: Well, ok... I'm not a linuxian...  I entered in the command prompt "-std=c++17", which gave "command not found", then i tried "gcc -std=c++17" which gave "command not found"... I tried to open a chat with you, to avoid spamming here... How do we do that? O.o Also, the line "std::cout << __cplusplus;" in the "main" of my small programm gave nothing, the real NOTHING... I must miss something somewhere... I have some knowledge about programming and computer science, but things like "__cplusplus is a macro defined to an integral type" mean nothing to me :(